# AES-128 8th round bit fault propagation

Tags: aes, side-channel-attack

It's well known that by injecting a byte fault during the 8th round of AES 128 just before the mix column the  key can be recovered with $2^{32}$-key space. A brute force attack is then possible but it takes some time.

If instead a byte fault, it is just a bit flip does it reduce the key space for K10? And  why?

In fact I was wondering if there is a kind of propagation of a 1 bit diff between the 8th round and 9th round that could reduce the key space for K10

Comment: If you do a search on the web you'll find a lot of papers describing such kind of attack.

Comment: For instance this one: https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/575.pdf

Comment: Welcome to crypto.se - here is some advice to help improve your question and get better answers: On stackexchange sites, it is expected for you to share your research and provide examples. If you hover over the upvote button, the text that appears is `This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear`.  Leaving it to others to go out of their way to find examples does not make for a well researched question.